# Android highlighted text event listener that is not context menu based

Tags: android

I noticed that when I "longclick" on a specific message in apps like FB, Viber, & Whatsapp, it will open up either a floating context menu or default action bar context menu.

What I would like to know is if it's possible to listen to a highlighted parts of text event in that particular textview and open a totally custom menu like a tooltip with different actions, not relying on context menu action mode. So far, I was only able to implement long click listening to an entire textview wherein that custom tooltip will appear.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: it comes in mind a simpler solution where you include a hyperlink in the text and you catch the event, does it suit your needs?

Comment: @petrumo, thanks I tried that approach but seems buggy. I decided to use context menu for the actions to make it less complicated :p